# Chrome method to create URL from selected text

Tags: google-chrome, macros, context-menu, url, right-click

hi I am looking for a way, using Chrome, to jump to a URL based on the text that is selected. e.g:

I select some text from a web page with mouse (e.g. the word "item")

I then want to go to a configurable URL based on this, e.g. www.preconfiguredurl.com/search?item

thanks for any advice.

(this reworded to be function oriented and not a product request, after being judged off topic for that reason)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone also looked for this, it's possible with Chrome to do it by selecting the text, then right-clicking the text, then clicking "Copy link to highlight".

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10256233?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: That's useful but a different task to what I was asking originally. This suggestion allows making a link to jump into a page, and to specific text. What I asked was to jump out of the page, to an external fixed url, passing the specific text that was selected on the page. These are sort of opposites.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this.

The trick is to think of the URL as a search engine.

Then you can use an extension called "Context Menu Search" to configure it as a right-click context menu item.

There are actually two Chrome extensions with this name and both seem to work.

They use a separate list of search engines to the list that Chrome supports. They support any URL, so it need not be a search engine as such, just any URL you want to build.

Chrome's own configurable search engines only work as keywords in the URL bar I think, so there is no way to use them for selected text, or on a right click.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a chrome extension ***AnyLink***, it enables you to create link to any selected text and then share it to others. 
any chrome with AnyLink will scroll to and highlight your selected texts.
here is the extension:

[Chrome Extension - Any Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/any-link-safereliable-lin/mpflpgaobfpjcpefkdnpalfdodifkkgc)

### **Any Link - Safe&Reliable! link to any text**

Create link to any selected text quickly and share anywhere. Safe and reliable: NO network request and all done absolutely locally!
AnyLink enables you to create links to any selected text in any web pages with only 3 steps:
1. select the text you want to highlight
2. right click to show the context menu
3. click the `link to text` menu item.
the link to the text will be copied to clipboard right away, you can then paste the link anywhere or make a bookmark with the link.
The selected texts would scroll into view automatically and be highlighted when page is opened with your shared link.
AnyLink is absolutely safe and reliable since there are NO network request and all done absolutely locally!
Hope you like it.